# Communication with the menubar window from main process is not working

Tags: electron, menubar

I am using menubar(https://www.npmjs.com/package/menubar) and I need to send information to it from the main process, but it does not seem to be working.

Once my app loads it creates the menubar and also requests some information from the server. The server returns information about a user being a manager or not. That is confirmed to be working fine. If the user is a manager, I want to display a button in the menubar window.

/* main process */

```
menubar.window.webContents.send('is-a-manager', true)
```

/* renderer process - I import ipcRenderer*/

```
ipcRenderer('is-a-manager', (event, isManager) => {
   console.log(isManager);
})
```

The window inside the menubar should actually log "true", but it does not print anything.

Comment: NOTE: there is an issue in the code above that I do not have in my code... the code above should read: ipcRenderer.on(....).  I got the code working now, but I do not know why it works.It is weird, but when I set a timeout of 1 second, things work as expected. SetTimeout(()->{menubar.window.webContents.send('is-a-manager', true)}, 1000). Therefore, it has to be a problem with the way things are being loaded, but I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: why don't u edit your question then? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
ipcRenderer.on('is-a-manager', (event, isManager) => {
   console.log(isManager);
})
```

[ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener)

Comment: Yes, sorry. That was a mistake on the code I provided above. The way you described it is how I have it in my code and it still does not work.